# Alternative to using clip-path for background images

Tags: css, background-image, clip-path

I'm trying to make a triangular shaped background image overlay a full width image.

[image]

It is easy enough to make a triangular shaped background image using border-with, border-color and background-image, like so:

```
border-width: 350px 50vw 0px 0px;
border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
background-image: url(/img/rainbow4.jpg);
```

But as there is white space you cannot overlay on top of another image, you get the following http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ENVWRz

If you set:

```
border-color: transparent transparent transparent transparent;
```

Then the image will appear square, so this doesn't work.

I've managed to make it work using clip-path, but this is very poorly supported across many browsers – so I am trying to avoid this approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can also take a look at mix-blend-mode or background-blend-mode , but also tricky to use  and not so much supported yet.

```css
div.triangle_test {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 350px 50vw 0px 0px;
  border-color: white transparent transparent transparent;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url('http://img06.deviantart.net/25de/i/2012/134/3/1/037_by_koko_stock-d4zq28i.jpg');
}
div.full_width {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  background-image: url('http://somebodymarketing.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Stock-Dock-House.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle_test"></div>
<div class="full_width"></div>
```

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JRdEVO